# Looking for a JavaScript library for displaying calendar data

Tags: javascript, calendar

I'm looking for a JavaScript calendar which can be used for displaying data in a nice calendar view. I would need to provide the calendar with a list of established events which have dates and other information, such as a URL to link to and text to be displayed on the calendar. I would also need to tell the calendar which view to render, whether it be a year, month, or even week.

Unfortunately my Google-Fu is failing me as every calendar I find is used for selecting a date as an input. I'd be willing to pay money, but even [CodeCanyon](http://codecanyon.net/category/javascript/calendars) doesn't have anything decent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to use something based on jQuery, a number of folks appear to be happy with [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/).

I haven't used it myself, but it has day/week/month support out of the box, and hooks to let you populate, retrieve/store, change look and feel, etc.

P.S. The Google search that I used was `intitle:calendar jquery day month week`